# How do you correctly announce a raise in live poker?

Tags: live, etiquette, casino, raise

**Setting:**
We are on the flop. After a few checks a player bets $500, and I am next in line.

**My goal:**
I want to raise to $1500 (in my mind I want to triple his bet). I want to eliminate string betting via use of verbal announcement. How do I accomplish this?

**Possible announcements(I think):**

1. "raise $1000"
2. "raise to $1500"
3. "raise $1500"

**What I know:**
I must or at least should push the correct amount of chips in one single motion into the pot.

Comment: The answers given are good. Just be aware of "house rules" on such issues.

Comment: I house rule I ran into was at Union Plaza long ago, if you simply said raise, without stating  an amount you were stuck with a minimum raise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Raise to 1500` is the clearest and most unambiguous.

You can also just say `Raise` and put the 1500 chips out there. It's not as good etiquette though as it requires the dealer to count it or potentially ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing required to make a raise is to put the chips involved in both the call and the raise forward.

If you do without an announcement, this needs to be done in a single motion, otherwise you may be penalised for string-betting and stuck with a minimum raise (or even a call only, if you had put out less chips than a call plus half the minimum raise altogether).

If you wish to guarantee a raise, say so "I raise" or "raise" is sufficient to assure you can make at least the minimum raise. Again, to prevent string-betting penalties and ensure it is more than minimum raise, put the chips forward in a single action.

If you wish to guarantee your raise amount, state it clearly - "I raise to 200" or "I raise, 200 more" mean different things and you should use the one you mean, or some variation of them. Once you have declares the raise and additional or total amount, it doesn't matter how you put the chips forward, as long as you put forward the correct amount quickly enough (or more than the correct amount and expect change).

An exception to this is to raise the maximum, i.e. all in. You may not need to put any chips forward if the dealer has all-markers, but be helpful and ensure they are within easy reach in the event of side pots or a pot-bet (as is common with PLO).

Answer (score 0):

One you do not need to announce raise, simply push enough chips out in one push, I f you are unable to do that Announce in a clear voice Raise, and it is good practice to announce the amount, There is a rule that was gaining a little traction, that said if you announce raise without the amount, you stuck with the minimum raise.dont announce thw amount in the abstract like saying I raise the pot, dealers are not supposed to say the pot size or count the pot in normal play. WOu may get by with it, but it also may confuse things enough where the game is delayed enough that a floor person needs to come make a ruling you may not like.